# XQuery Error when reading attribute from parentnode with *typed* XML (value() requires a singleton)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I have a simple XML:

```
DECLARE @x1 xml = '<r>
    <o a="1">
        <o a="2">
        </o>
    </o>
</r>';
```

And select the following:

```
SELECT r.o.value('(../@a)[1]','varchar(20)') FROM @x1.nodes('/r//o') r(o);
```

Everything is nice:

```
NULL
1
```

When I use typed XML:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [dbo].test AS '
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="r">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="o" type="o" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="o">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="o" type="o" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="a" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>'
GO

DECLARE @x2 xml(dbo.test) = '<r>
    <o a="1">
        <o a="2">
        </o>
    </o>
</r>';

SELECT r.o.value('(../@a)[1]','varchar(20)') FROM @x2.nodes('/r//o') r(o);
```

I got the Error:

```
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

Why does the untyped XML works and the typed XML not?

Comment: StackOverflow has always objected to things like short questions and short answers, requiring you to pad them with rubbish in order to satisfy its rules checker. Looks like it's getting worse. Just keep pumping out the padding and hope they'll improve the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you well understand that this is not the usual problem of having to convince the parser that there is only one thing being passed into `value()`. This problem is specific to **typed XML**, as you have observed.

Using google I found [this ancient blogpost](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/fun-with-static-xquery-evaluation-1/) with the promising text

rt is part of the XQuery 1.0/XPath 2.0 data model.

> Most people get by that. The real fun starts when you do examples using untyped XML and XPath expressions with the text() node test. text() works just fine when using untyped XML, but **fails against typed XML with simple content**

It talks about the SQL Books Online and the SQL Server 2005 XML Best Practices paper, which I *think* is [this book here](https://studylib.net/doc/7684133/bulk-loading-xml-data). I haven't looked for a more up-to-date reference. But using what I found there I *have* been able to fix your problem: Simple replace

```
SELECT r.o.value('(../@a)[1]','varchar(20)') FROM @x2.nodes('/r//o') r(o);
```

with

```
SELECT r.o.value('fn:string(../@a)[1]','varchar(20)') FROM @x2.nodes('/r//o') r(o);
```

Basically, `value()` doesn't like being given values of a typed-xml-type, but wants strings. So we give it a string.